# retrieve image from mongo database [multer express nodejs]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, multer

It seems there are countless tutorials on how to upload but none on retrieving.

This is my Schema:

```
var bDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    img: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
});
```

My Setup:

```
app.use(multer({ storage: storage }).single('photo'));
```

I have manged to upload the image to the db and what I'm trying to do is send this data to an ejs template like so:

```
app.get("/b", function(req, res){
    bData.find({}, function(err, found){
       if(err){
          console.log(err);
       }else{
          res.render("b", {found: found});
       }
    });
});
```

Then on the ejs template i want:

```
<img src="<%=found.img.data%>">
```

Also should mention the image data path: `public/uploads`

Comment: I think you should call your image like this `<img src="<%=found.img%>">`  in your ejs template, since the variable that express return with your data will be named `found`

Comment: yes thats what i meant

Comment: Oh ok, it's seems that your stocking your image as a buffer so your src attribute should look like this : `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%=found.img.toString('base64')%>">`  not sure of the ejs syntax thought, long time I didn't play with ejs.

Comment: thanks i'll try this but can i say 'image/*' instead of 'image/jpeg'

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: you might want to pass your `found.img.contentType`

Comment: True. Found out 'image/*' works too.

Comment: Nice ! Mind if I create a complete answer with all that we said and you accept it ?

Comment: No not at all, please do so

Comment: Should also mention that it's `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%=found.img.data.toString('base64')%>">` since the buffer is inside data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here was how to insert a buffered image in an `img` tag.

To do so your image tag have to be like this :

`<img src='data:image/(contentType);base64,(buffer).toString("base64")'>` where contentType can be jpeg/gif/png/.../* and buffer is your buffered image.

In ejs it might look like this :

`<img src="data:image/<%=found.img.contentType%>;base64,<%=found.img.data.toString('base64')%>">`